# not working .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

i made .htaccess file but it's some time not working properly. getting some error and page is working. i am not good in .htaccess program.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php

RewriteRule ^page1?$ page1.php
RewriteRule ^page2?$ page2.php
RewriteRule ^page3?$ page3.php
RewriteRule ^page4?$ page4.php
RewriteRule ^page5?$ page5.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-\_]+)$ profile.php?a=$1

ErrorDocument 404 "<H1>Page not found</H1>"
```

i have this type link :

1)www.example.com?profile.php?user=userid
i need : www.example.com/userid

2)www.example.com/about.php
i need : www.example.com/about

3)www.example.com?list.php?list=5
i need www.example.com/list/5

what can i do?

Comment: I fail to see the connection between the dynamic configuration file you posted (".htaccess") and the URL mapping ideas you indicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not exactly precise in what it asks, but I will try to give it a shot:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/?about$ /about.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/?list/(\d+)$ /list.php?list=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 "<H1>Page not found</H1>"
```